# Docx4j TOC generation getting wrong page number

Tags: java, xhtml, docx4j

I'm using docxj4 for generating Word documents, and now I need to generate a table of contents. I am using docx4j-export-fo library for that purpose. But it produces the wrong numbering.
I need to start the toc from page number 4 and pass the start index accordingly to the toc generator method. But still, I am getting the wrong page numbers into the TOC.
Any suggestion to solve it.
Thanks

```
TocGenerator tocGenerator = new TocGenerator(wordMLPackage);
tocGenerator.generateToc(PASS_SOME_INDEX_HERE, TocHelper.DEFAULT_TOC_INSTRUCTION, false);
```

Comment: The numbering inaccuracies are likely due to the differing page layout models (ie FO versus Word).  An alternative is to use Word, via https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-documents4j-local/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/documents4j/local/TocOperations.java

Comment: Thanks @JasonPlutext it's working for me on my local windows machine. But i am getting following error when deployed to the linux server.  org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessInitException: Could not execute [cmd, /S, /C, ""/root/temp_documents4j_local/word_start1923523066.vbs""] in /root/temp_documents4j_local. Error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: I think the reason of this exception is that VBS scripts is not available on linux. Is there some way to make it working on linux.

Comment: documents4j local must run on a Windows machine (because it runs Word).  You can run documents4j on a remote Windows machine; see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/docx4j-samples-documents4j-remote but you will have to build into the vbs the necessary stuff for TOC generation.

Comment: So there is no way to fix it without using the documents4j ?? I mean can't i fix it with docx4j and export-fo ?

Comment: You have the docx4j source code, so you can dig into it to understand your issue better and potentially solve it.